# The result of the sqlalchemy query return tuple but I want to as a list

Tags: python, flask

I used below code:

```
session.query(Content).order_by(desc(Content.date)).limit(25).offset(0)
```

I get result, it filter my repeat data, but I hope save this repeat data.
I know the sqlalchemy query result as tuple.

How to do or code not use tuple return query result ?

Comment: do `list(s)` on your `s` tuple.

Comment: list(s) ?    waht's mean? No, No, I used it no any changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in [the docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.all):

> all()
>
> Return the results represented by this Query as a list.
>   This results in an execution of the underlying query.

So this should work:

```
session.query(Content).order_by(desc(Content.date)).limit(25).offset(0).all()
```